# How can I connect pg-promise with RDS proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pg-promise

I currently have an AWS RDS instance setup with a Proxy that manages connections. I am trying to connect to that proxy with pg-promise but I am getting an `Error: Task timed out after 3.00 seconds`.

I have tried to initialize the pgp connection the way I normally would and simply switched the host parameter with the proxy endpoint. The following is all found in one lambda file but I'll split it up for clarity:

Here I initialize (this stuff is before the handler):

```
const initOptions = {

    // pg-promise initialization options...

    task(e) {
        if (e.ctx.finish) {
            // this is a task->finish event;
            console.log('Duration:', e.ctx.duration);
            if (e.ctx.success) {
                // e.ctx.result = resolved data;
            } else {
                // e.ctx.result = error/rejection reason;
            }
        } else {
            // this is a task->start event;
            console.log('Start Time:', e.ctx.start);
        }
    }
}

const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions)
```

connect to db(also before the handler)

```
let connection = {
    host: process.env.proxyendpoint,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    database: process.env.DB,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
}

const db = pgp(connection)
```

the handler that is run when lambda is called

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
     ...
     try {
        console.log('before insert')
        const res = await getInsertUser({...event.body, token, chatUsername}) 
        console.log('after insert') <------ this is never reached
        // if new user, create one direct channel with me 
        ...
        return formatResponse(res)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return formatError(error)
    }
```

this is the insert user function (tried it with and without the `await`)

```
const getInsertUser = async (userData) => {
    return await db.task('getInsertUser', async t => {
        console.log('insert user callback fired') <---- this is never reached 
        const user = await t.oneOrNone('SELECT * FROM users WHERE unique_id = ${profile.sub}', userData);
        if (user) {
            return { ...user, userAlreadyExists: true }
        } else {
            const newUser = await t.one('INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, chat_token, chat_username) VALUES(${profile.sub}, ${profile.nickname}, ${profile.email}, ${token}, ${chatUsername}) RETURNING *', userData);
            return {...newUser, userAlreadyExists: false }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: All PostgreSQL libraries (at least under NodeJS) are plagued with connectivity issues under Lambda, which is what you need to research specifically. [You can find plenty of issues logged within the core library](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues?q=Lambda), there are some solutions there that can help.